# MS SQL replication run only with system account

Tags: sql-server, sql, replication, sql-server-2012, transactional-replication

I'm trying to configure a new replication with SQL Server 2012

- I configured the distribution
- While configuring the publication, it asked for a user to run the snapshot agent. I set a strong user with the right permissions to the snapshot folder.

Now I'm getting the following error:

> A required privilege is not held by the client. The step failed. – SQL Job Fails with error

The snapshot worked when changing the the SQL agent account to local system, but for security reasons, I need to run the SQL agent with a specific Windows account.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The Snapshot Agent Windows account must at minimum be a member of the **db_owner** fixed database role in the publication and distribution database and have read, write, and modify permissions on the snapshot share.  This is covered in the section ***Permissions That Are Required by Agents*** in [Replication Agent Security Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151868.aspx).